# Why does the ArcMap exported KMZ always show my local path information when displayed in Google Maps API?

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, google-maps-api, kmz

I used [ArcMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcMap) (arcpy) to export shapefiles into KMZ and then display them via Google Maps API v3. It looks fine initally:

[image]

But when I hover my mouse above the KMZ and click it, it will alway show my local path information:

[image]

It is very annoying. Is there a solution to avoid this? I just want the KMZ to show the shape...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using arcpy, you will be able to modify how the KMZ is exported.
I am not sure if that is the kml_document or kml_id attribute controlling your hoover/click, but essentially you can control what value is in both of those attributes. See the [KML documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut).

Also, [an excellent webcast from FME](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCbWq0v0jeY&feature=youtu.be&t=1s) (even though that is not the software you are using) should give you some ideas about how to control the document, name, id, and the balloon. [And more from FME](http://www.safe.com/solutions/for-applications/google-earth-maps/).

Whether it only shows that information when you click that is controlled by the balloon tag.

Comment: I figured it out, just by adding "{suppressInfoWindows: true}"